# How to remove /cpanel after domain name

Tags: authentication, cpanel

Hello so My question is simple but I didn’t find the answer anywhere In internet, I have a domain name but I don’t want when users for example add (/cpanel) after the domain name  redirect them to the cpanel login page Instead of redirecting to cpanel login page I just want to show 404, I think my question is clear now, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a `root` user in order to edit these in cPanel/WHM. These are already in EA4 Template so cannot be removed or edited by a cPanel user. If you're a root user, do the following:

```
cp -via /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/ea4_main.default /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/ea4_main.local
```

(Do not edit ea4_main.default as it will be overwritten)

Afterwards, edit the file `/var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/ea4_main.local`

Here are the lines you'll have to remove:

```
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?cpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi
```

You can remove all following lines to stop all redirects:

```
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?controlpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?cpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?kpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securecontrolpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sredirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securecpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sredirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securewhm/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/swhmredirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?webmail$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/wredirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?webmail/ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/wredirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?whm/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/whmredirect.cgi
```

Save the file. Run the following commands to rebuild Apache configuration:

```
/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
/scripts/restartsrv_httpd
```

Redirects are gone!!!